# How do I find Azure ARM template output properties for a resoruce

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

When writing the outputs part of ARM template how do the do what properties are available for a resource. in the below example for public ip resource how do I find out  dnsSettings.fqdn or .ipAddress is available

```
"outputs": {
    "fqdn": {
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_name')).dnsSettings.fqdn]",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "ipaddress": {
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_name')).ipAddress]",
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ask is related to [Retrieve FQDN of Azure SQL from a linkted template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069684/retrieve-fqdn-of-azure-sql-from-a-linkted-template/55102237#55102237) question.

The easiest way to accomplish your requirement is illustrated in below screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Note: If you think your question has been answered then please 'accept' it, if just helped then click "This answer is useful" and provide an up vote. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: You can also use resource explorer in the portal to "browse" resources you have provisioned in Azure...

Comment: This is dependent on how the Az / Azure PowerShell libraries decide to represent the resource as an object. It may correspond to the properties on the resource, or it may not.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've found, using only ARM, is to output the whole object:

```
    "outputs": {
    "ipaddress": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_name'))]"
    }
```

When you apply the policy, the output will show all the possible properties and their values.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the whole data structure in json at https://resources.azure.com.

Answer (score 0):

you dont really know, because some properties are amended by default (and the other answer doesnt mention that at all, which could mislead you badly). One thing you can do is look at the rest api definition of the resource and use `Full` reference to the resource, that way you will always get what you see in the api definition.

```
reference(parameters('publicIPAddresses_name'), 'api-version', 'Full')
```

but, object structure will be different, as far as I remember you'd need to access properties of the object for the most of the output. What I tend to do is - create a template that does nothing but output the existing object I'm interested in and run it and examine the output.

Outputs are almost never needed so it's not that big of an issue in my mind.

Rest Api definitions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/